# Difference between Job Queue,Input Queue and Ready Queue?

Tags: operating-system

Could someone explain what exactly is the function of all the 3 queues and how are they different from each other? It would be great if you could also tell where exactly the queue resides (i.e Main memory or Disk). Thanks!

**Edit:** I want to know their function with respect to them being used for queueing processes in UNIX based Operating Systems.

Comment: What's the context in which you see the mention of "all the 3 queues"?

Answer (score 2):

Jobs and their queues are **abstract concepts** with many different implementations (see [Wikipedia: Job queue](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Job_queue) and [Wikipedia: Job scheduler](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Job_scheduler)) which then define their meaning. Input queue and ready queue fall into the same "*abstract*" category.

For example: the Windows AT command can schedule and execute jobs in the form of arbitrary OS shell command and the job queue resides almost in [Wikipedia: Windows Registry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Registry) which resides on disk but for performance reasons is also cached in the main memory. See http://ss64.com/nt/at.html for more details